# How to reconcile contrast model (of similarity judgment) with anchor-and-adjust?

Tags: decision-making, anchoring

Hastie & Dawes (2009) claims that humans judge whether an instance belongs to a class using the contrast model, where "we perceive similarity by making (very rapid) comparisons of the attributes of two or more entities whose similarity is being evaluated."  (Hastie & Dawes (2009).  *Rational Choice in an Uncertain World*, p. 106)

The book also claims that we often judge using an anchor-and-adjust strategy, considering one factor at a time because of "our limited attention 'channels' and the selective strategies we have developed to deal with that cognitive limit."  (p. 72)

Do we employ an anchor-and-adjust strategy when employing the contrast model, i.e., are we contrasting one feature at a time, most salient feature first?  Alternatively, are there situations in which we are forced to work with one variable at a time, but other situations in which we can simultaneously compare multiple variables?